# Notification Java Script (jsNotifications) Change for run without click on a PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, notifications

Hello I need to make a notification in java script, my web page will change the language of the page to show the web page in the language of the client.

I use this code:

```
if ($client_languaje == $system_actual_languaje) {
    // Idioma Correcto
} else {
if ($client_languaje == "es") {
    $red_idioma = "Spanish";
header('Location: index.php?&language=$red_idioma');
} else if ($client_languaje == "en") {
    $red_idioma = "English";
header('Location: index.php?&language=$red_idioma');

    } else {
            $red_idioma = "English";
header('Location: index.php?&language=$red_idioma');
        }

}
```

I need to make notification to the client that the language has change or that I doesn’t offer a translate for that language. I like more graphical the java script notifications. 
I will like to use this: jsNotifications (http: // code.google. com /p/jsnotifications/).

This is a example of the notification I want to show: http://www.lewebmonster.com/proyectos/classes-javascript/jsNotifications/demo/

You can download if need using this link: http://www.lewebmonster.com/proyectos/classes-javascript/jsNotifications/lewebmonster-clase-javascript-jsnotifications.zip

I now that I need to load:

**And this java script run on a clic:**

```
$(function(){
    //create a new instance of jsNotifications class and set up the general settings 
    var objInstanceName=new jsNotifications({
        autoCloseTime : 10,
        showAlerts: true,
        title: 'Notificación de Lenguaje'
    });

    //check the browser support
    if(objInstanceName.isAvailable()){
        //show the bar to Chrome/Chromium users
        if(objInstanceName.getStatus()==1) $('#divBottomBar').fadeIn(1200);
    }   
    //error message
    $('#btnError').on('click',function(){
        objInstanceName.show('error','Todavía no contamos con la traducción de tu idioma, ponemos a tu disposición el traductor google para que te ayude a traducir nuestra web',false,
        'Error en Lenguaje');
    });
    //ok message
    $('#btnOK').on('click',function(){
        objInstanceName.show('ok','Su idioma fue modificado automáticamente para que se sienta más cómodo, puede revertir esta función seleccionando el idioma manualmente del menú desplegable.');
    });

    //show html notification
    $('#btnHTML').on('click',function(){
        objInstanceName.showHTML('message.html',true);
    });
});
```

**I need to have something like this:**

```
If ($a == “a”) {
//show were the notification without need a click on a button
}
```

I think that I need to change on('click',function… and call from PHP but I need some help to make this function. 
I will appreciate and render thanks your help.

Regards, Alex!

Answer (score 0):

$('#body_id').onload(function(){
//execute the code of the function which determines you clients language

})

Comment: Thanks por the replay johny! i have a question i use this code to run the java script when i load? Regards, alex